# Nonlinear minimum Mean Square Error estimation

Tags: estimation, nonlinear, mse

Let say I have the following parameter to estimate:

$$ \theta = \frac{1}{\mu^2 - 1} \ .$$

The observed measurement is $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$. The mean $\mu$ is unknown. There are two cases I am interested in:

1. The value $\sigma$ is known
2. The value of $\frac{\sigma}{\mu}$ is known

What is a [minimum mean square error (MMSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_mean_square_error) estimator $\hat{\theta}(x) = \text{argmin}_{\theta_0(x)} \mathbb{E}[(\theta_0(x) - \theta)^2] $ for the given function? Will it be unbiased?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense when the words are interpreted in standard ways.  A "parameter" cannot be a function of data like $\bar x.$  Could you clarify what kind of object $\theta_0$ is?

Comment: @whuber, $\theta$ is an estimand (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimand) and $\theta_0$ is the value when measurement $x$ doesn't have noise $\epsilon$. If it makes sense now, please edit the question using the correct terminology.

Comment: It doesn't make sense yet because an estimand, by definition, cannot be a statistic such as $\bar x.$  The target of an estimator (which is what $\theta$ is intended to be) *must* be a definite property of the underlying distribution from which the data are sampled.  You are using the symbol "$x$" in two distinct senses, both as a random value and as a parameter.

Comment: @whuber, I've modified accordingly using $\mathbb{E}[x]$, which is a definite value, instead of $\bar{x}$.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to ask for a minimum-variance estimator of $1/(\mu^2-1)$ based on an observation from $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$?  If so, is $\sigma$ known or not?

Comment: @whuber, yes, this is what I wanted. Thanks! There are two cases that I am interested in: when $\sigma$ is known and when $\frac{\sigma}{\mu}$ is known.